# Angularjs, scope.$watch внутри directive

Tags: angularjs

Задача простая - получить данные с сервера и отобразить их в виде таблицы и графика(D3). С запросом и таблицей никаких проблем. А вот график я решил запихнуть в отдельную директиву, но никак не могу добиться корректного срабатывания $watch для изменения переменной из $scope.

HTML

```
<graph></graph>
```

shcema.js

```
angular.module('schema', ['mui', 'network', 'errors'])
   .config(function ($locationProvider) {
       $locationProvider.html5Mode({
           enabled    : true,
           requireBase: false
       });
   })
   .controller('schema', [
       '$scope', 'api', '$location', 'error',
       function ($scope, api, $location, error) {
           $scope.data = {};
           api.request('getSystemTree', {ci: $location.search().ci})
              .subscribe(function (d) {
                  $scope.data = d;
                  $scope.$apply();
                  console.log(d)  // Запрос отрабатывает, данные приходят
              });
           $scope.goToSm   = function (ci) {window.open(api.smURI(ci));};
           $scope.getError = error.description;
       }])
   .directive('graph', function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope   : false,
           link    : function (scope, element, attrs) {
               // Наблюдатель отрабатывает 1 раз и выводит Object {} undefined undefined
               scope.$watch(scope.data, function (n, o) {console.log(scope.data, o, n);})
           }
       }
   });
```

Гуглинг запутал меня окончательно. Объясните, что я делаю не так? Может вообще по другому надо?

Comment: сделай чуть полнее пример. Пока возможно, что ты неправильно задал watch: или `scope.$watch('data",function(){...})` или `scope.$watch(function(){ return scope.data;}, function(){...})`

Comment: @Grundy `scope.$watch("data", function (n, o) {console.log(scope.data);})` помогло. Спасибо огромное. Оформите как ответ, дабы плюсануть и принять можно было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации: [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) первым параметром принимает либо функцию, либо строку.

В твоем случае передается объект, который по всей видимости первоначально приводился к строке.

Из-за этого, отслеживалось совсем другое свойство объекта `scope`.

Для решения нужно либо использовать строку `"data"`

```
scope.$watch("data", function (n, o) {console.log(scope.data, o, n);})
```

Либо использовать функцию возвращающую нужный объект

```
scope.$watch(function(){ return scope.data; }, function (n, o) {console.log(scope.data, o, n);})
```